# Sorting before GROUP BY - not working

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I need to perform a sort ***before*** the GROUP BY clause, but MySQL does not want to cooperate.

```
SELECT `article`, `date`, `aip`
FROM `official_prices`
WHERE `article` = 2003
GROUP BY `article`
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

The row that should be picked is the one with the earliest date (2013-07-15) but instead it picks the date that comes first in table order. Changing to `DESC` does no difference.

First image shows both rows, ungrouped. Second image is them being grouped.

[image]

This table is being joined to by a main query, so (I think) any solutions involving `LIMIT 1` won't be useful to me.

Full query:

```
SELECT `articles`.*, `official_prices`.`aip`
FROM `articles`
LEFT JOIN `official_prices`
ON (`official_prices`.`article` = `articles`.`id`)
GROUP BY `articles`.`id`, `official_prices`.`article`
ORDER BY `official_prices`.`date` ASC, `articles`.`name`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `group by` and `order` like that. The order will only apply to the complete record set being returned and not in the group itself. This will work:

```
select o1.* 
from official_prices o1
inner join
(
  SELECT `article`, min(`date`) as mdate
  from `official_prices`
  WHERE `article` = 2003
  GROUP BY `article`
) o2 on o1.article = o2.article and o1.date = o2.mdate
```

Comment: Can you adjust your answer with my full query somehow?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is simply incorrect.  The ordering before the `group by` does not have a (guaranteed) effect on the results.

My guess is that you want to get the most recent `date` and `aip` for that date.  Here is a better approach:

```
SELECT `article`, max(`date`),
       substring_index(group_concat(`aip` order by date desc), ',', 1) as lastAip
FROM `official_prices`
WHERE `article` = 2003
GROUP BY `article`;
```

The only downside is that the `group_concat()` will convert any value to a string.  If it is some other type (and a string poses problems), then convert it back to the desired type.

Actually, an even better approach is to skip the `group by` entirely, because you are already filtering down to one article:

```
select article, `date`, aip
from official_prices
where article = 2003
order by `date` desc
limit 1;
```

The first approach works for multiple articles.

EDIT:

Your full query is:

```
SELECT `articles`.*, `official_prices`.`aip`
FROM `articles` LEFT JOIN
     `official_prices`
     ON `official_prices`.`article` = `articles`.`id`
GROUP BY `articles`.`id`, `official_prices`.`article`
ORDER BY `official_prices`.`date` ASC, `articles`.`name`;
```

You are looking for more than one article, so the second approach won't work.  So, use the first:

```
SELECT `articles`.*,
       substring_index(group_concat(`official_prices`.`aip` order by `official_prices`.`date` desc),
                       ',', 1) as lastAIP
FROM `articles` LEFT JOIN
     `official_prices`
     ON `official_prices`.`article` = `articles`.`id`
GROUP BY `articles`.`id`, `official_prices`.`article`
ORDER BY `articles`.`name`;
```

Comment: See my full query. Where can I put a `LIMIT 1` clause within the JOIN?

Comment: The GROUP_CONCAT solution is so hackish. Surely MySQL must have been better designed than this?